# Calculating Average from a list of students taken from a .txt file

Tags: java, properties, stream, average, filereader

I have a separated .txt file in which there is a list of "students" with their own mark on the side that goes from 0 to 10, here is an example on how the .txt looks like:

> Mark 2
>   Elen 3
>   Luke 7
>   Elen 9
>   Jhon 5
>   Mark 4
>   Elen 10
>   Luke 1
>   Jhon 1
>   Jhon 7
>   Elen 5
>   Mark 3
>   Mark 7

What I want to do is calculating the Average of each student (expressed in `double`) so that the output would look like this:

```
Mark: 4.0
Elen: 6.75
Luke: 4.0
Jhon: 4.33
```

Here is what I've come up with, for now I've only managed to use `Properties` to list the student names without repetition, but the number shown on the side of each one of them is obviously the last one the program finds.
I've included it on a button actionlistener as I'm implementing a GUI, by pressing the button the output shown above is `append` in a `TextArea`:

```
 b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent d) {

   try {
      File file = new File("RegistroVoti.txt");
      FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
      Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.load(fileInput);
      fileInput.close();

      Enumeration enuKeys = properties.keys();
      while (enuKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = (String) enuKeys.nextElement();
        String value = properties.getProperty(key);
        l1.append(key + ": " + value + "\n");
      }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
});
```

I was thinking to use `Collectors` to calculate the average, but I actually don't know how to implement it...

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For future use learn collection. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_collections.htm

Comment: You could use a `HashMap` which stores key value pairs...Your key would be the name of the student and your value could be an `ArrayList` of scores. After you have read the file you could iterate over the `HashMap` and calculate the average for each student based on the `ArrayList` of scores.

Comment: Using properties will not work as the property Mark will only have one value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I like to do this kind of thing is using `Map`s and `List`s.

To read the lines from the file, I'm fond of the [`nio`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) way of reading, so I would do

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("RegistroVoti.txt"));
```

Then, you can make a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)`<String,`[`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)`<Integer>>`, which will store each person's name and a list of the numbers associated with them:

```
HashMap<String, List<Integer>> studentMarks = new HashMap<>();
```

Then, using a for each loop, go through each of the lines and add each number to the hash map:

```
for (String line : lines) {
    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
    if (studentMarks.get(parts[0]) == null) {
        studentMarks.put(parts[0], new ArrayList<>());
    }
    studentMarks.get(parts[0]).add(Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
}
```

Then, you can go through each entry in the map and calculate the average of the associated list:

```
for (String name : studentMarks.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(name + " " + studentMarks.get(name).stream().mapToInt(i -> i).average().getAsDouble());
}
```

(Note that this is a Java 8 [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) solution; you could just as easily write a `for` loop to calculate it in earlier versions)

For more information on some of the things I've used, see:

- [`String#split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)
- [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)
- [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
- [`Stream<T>#mapToInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-)

Hope this helps!

**Edit** A complete solution:

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent d) {
        try {
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("RegistroVoti.txt"));

            Map<String, List<Integer>> studentMarks = new HashMap<>();

            for (String line : lines) {
                String[] parts = line.split(" ");

                if (studentMarks.get(parts[0]) == null) {
                    studentMarks.put(parts[0], new ArrayList<>());
                }
                studentMarks.get(parts[0]).add(Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
            }

            for (String name : studentMarks.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(name + " " + studentMarks.get(name).stream().mapToInt(i -> i).average().getAsDouble());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer! All my problems were successfully solved and I also learnt new things! However I should need some hints for another thing I have to make... I would like to print in a `TextArea` a **Vertical Histogram** containing the occurrences of every single vote in the .txt file ( Ex: "1" would have 2 askterisks, "2" would have 1 askerisk and so on), I've searched around but unfortunately I coudn't write a solution that compiles correctly.

Comment: @TobiaZamò I'm glad I could help. Your request is too long to be answered in a comment; it would be better for you to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (if you haven't already). That way, people can post complete answers, and you can ask a complete question, with what you've tried.