# Vertical histogram not showing properly

Tags: java, char, java.util.scanner, histogram, charat

This question is quite related to the one I made 4 days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375763/calculating-average-from-a-list-of-students-taken-from-a-txt-file).
What I need to do is creating a **Vertical Histogram** which reads the occurencies of students's grades (from 1 to 10) that are listed in a .txt file like this:

> Mark 2
>   Elen 3
>   Luke 7
>   Elen 9
>   Jhon 5
>   Mark 4
>   Elen 10
>   Luke 1
>   Jhon 1
>   Jhon 7
>   Elen 5
>   Mark 3
>   Mark 7

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class GradeHistogram {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("RegistroVoti.txt"));
    String line;
    char currentChar;
    int [] array = new int [10];
    int max = 0, currentValue;

    while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
      line = fileScan.nextLine();
      for(int j=0; j < line.length(); j++) {

        currentChar = line.charAt(j);

        if (currentChar == '1')
          array[0]++;
        else if (currentChar == '2')
          array[1]++;
        else if (currentChar == '3')
          array[2]++;
        else if (currentChar == '4')
          array[3]++;
        else if (currentChar == '5')
          array[4]++;
        else if (currentChar == '6')
          array[5]++;
        else if (currentChar == '7')
          array[6]++;
        else if (currentChar == '8')
          array[7]++;
        else if (currentChar == '9')
          array[8]++;
        else if (currentChar == '0')
          array[9]++;
      }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
      if (array[i] > max)
        max = array[i]; 
    }
    currentValue = max;
    for(int i = max;  i > 0; i--) {
      for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if(array[j] < i)
          System.out.print(" ");
        else
          System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("12345678910");
  }
}
```

However since the `charAt()` method prints an asterisk based on the single `char` he founds, it adds the askerisks that are on "10" in the number "1" column.

I actually tried the `nextInt()` method by modifying the code, but when I ran it, no asterisks were shown...

How can I solve this?

Any feedback is appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to extract the grade from the line. Use `Integer.parseInt` on that part to get the number instead of trying to implement the parsing yourself:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.+ (\\d+)$");

while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
    line = fileScan.nextLine();
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
        array[Integer.parseInt(m.group(1))-1]++;
    }
}
```